# Decode the Secret Message

Tags: cipher

Decode the Secret Message :

10110111100110101001001110010011100100001101001111011111100010001001000010001101100100111001101111011110

Hints-

> some may not apply, figure out what ones do: inverted, backwards, binary, hex, letters

Comment: Put hints in spoilers next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Hello, world!

The trick is

> to divide into 8 bit binary, invert them, and convert to ASCII

As follows:

> 1011 0111 -> 0100 1000 -> H
> 1001 1010 -> 0110 0101 -> e
> 1001 0011 -> 0110 1100 -> l
>  1001 0011 -> 0110 1100 -> l
>  1001 0000 -> 0110 1111 -> o
>  1101 0011 -> 0010 1100 -> ,
>  1101 1111 -> 0010 0000 -> space
>  1000 1000 -> 0111 0111 -> w
>  1001 0000 -> 0110 1111 -> o
>  1000 1101 -> 0111 0010 -> r
>  1001 0011 -> 0110 1100 -> l
> 1001 1011 -> 0110 0100 -> d
>  1101 1110 -> 0010 0001 -> !